# HtttpURLConnection funções inexistentes no desenvolvimento Xamarin Forms (Conversão do sistema Java para C#)

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin-forms

Tenho um sistema desenvolvido no Android Studio e estou passando para Xamarin Forms em C# e esta acontecendo alguns erros que não estou conseguindo resolver

**Resumindo o que meu sistema faz:**
Ele pega a página html e transcreve linha por linha do html para que eu possa fazer algumas verificações.

Segue linhas as quais estou com problemas:

**if(httpURLConnection.getResponseCode() == 200)** getResponseCode não existente
**InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());** getInputStream() não existe

**BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));** a variável inputStream com problemas

```
    public string GetDados(string urlString)
    {
        string dados = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.OpenConnection();

            if(httpURLConnection.getResponseCode() == 200)
            {
                InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());

                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));

                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                string linha;

                while ((linha = bufferedReader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    stringBuilder.Append(linha);
                }

                dados = stringBuilder.ToString();

                httpURLConnection.Disconnect();

            }
        }
        catch (IOException erro)
        {

            return null;
        }

        return dados;
    }
```

Comment: Já passei por alguns problemas ao converter de Java pra C#. 
mas uma dica: Em c#, raramente ( pra não dizer nunca ) usam nomes como "get".  (devido aos get e set padrão da linguagem)

Você disse que não encontrou a getInputStream(). 
Tente "InputStream" no lugar sem os parenteses, tipo 

httpURLConnection.InputStream

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma bem mais simples de se efetuar o Download de um conteúdo da web é esta:

```
private async Task<string> DownloadContent(string url)
{
    using(var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        using(var r = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(url)))
        {
            return  await r.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Você precisará do pacote `HttpClient`.